# Modal view using UIModalPresentationFormSheet stays in memory (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a modal view with the UIModalPresentationFormSheet presentation style.

```
MPMediaItemCollection *albumItem = [self.albums objectAtIndex:index];
AlbumViewController *destination = [[AlbumViewController alloc] initWithAlbum:albumItem];
destination.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:destination animated:NO];
```

When the user taps outside the modal view, it is closed. However, it's still in memory, it's not released.

What's the correct way to deal with this?

Edit: is seems there's something inside AlbumViewController that's not being released properly. A bug on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. ARC will take care of deallocating the memory when it is needed.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827319/forcing-a-dealloc-or-getting-dealloc-sooner):

> ARC deallocs any object to which there are no more strong references. So to dealloc something, simply set all the variables pointing to it to nil and make sure the object is not involved in any circular reference.

Comment: "When needed" as determined by the OS? That's kind of crappy when debugging potential memory problems. Is it not possible to force the no longer used controller to be released?

Comment: I don't think so. Are you having memory problem?

Comment: Ok but when the modal view controller is closed, there shouldn't be any strong references to it, so it should be deallocated, right? But of course `*destination` is a strong reference under ARC, so in that case, I do think I have memory problems.

Comment: Okay so when I open and close the modal view controller 10 times, I do have 10 live instances of it, clearly visible in Instruments.

Comment: `destination` is just a local variable and will not constitute a strong reference after `present...` has been called unless you then go on to assign the view controller to an instance variable or anything else that will hold onto it.