# Understanding ViewController dealloc process

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I have a container `UIViewController` which does the following when removing one of its children:

```
- (void)removeChildWithIndex:(NSUInteger)Index {
  @autoreleasepool {
    ChildViewController *child = [_children objectAtIndex:Index];

    //Remove the child from the VC hierarchy
    [child willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [child.view removeFromSuperview];
    [child removeFromParentViewController];

    //Remove the child from array
    [_children removeObjectAtIndex:Index];
  }

  //Post a notification for anyone who might care
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RemovedChildNotification object:self];
}
```

The root of my problem  is that `child` is not being `dealloc`ed at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` block, but instead is released a little bit later (by the looks of it after the RunLoop has a chance to process an internal list of outstanding events):

[image]

This ordinarily wouldn't be a problem, but one object which is observing the `NSNotification` sent out at the end of the function above is relying on the `child` being `dealloc`ed before it receives the notification.

**Can anybody explain/link me to some documentation to help me understand why `child` isn't released immediately?**

Alternatively, if I have no choice about when `child` is `dealloc`ed, can anybody suggest a clean way of delaying my notification until after the `dealloc`? I suppose I could put a call in `[ChildViewController dealloc]` to inform the parent of its demise and fire off the notification at that point, but that's a pretty dirty way of doing it...

Comment: Isn't `willMoveToParentViewController` a delegate method?  Why are you calling it explicitly?  Why are you using an `@autoreleasepool`; I don't see any auto-release objects being created?  I think the best fix is to remove the requirement "relying on the child being dealloced".

Comment: Is the observer really dependent on the child being dealloced? As opposed to being dependent on it no longer having a parent?

Comment: @trojanfoe: [This is explained in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13), but I still find it to be a massively unintuitive: when adding a VC, `willMove...` is called implicity, `didMove...` must be called explicity. This opposite is true when removing.

Comment: @MikePollard: yes, I'm afraid it is dependent on it being dealloced.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at why that's the case. It sounds like an incredibly fragile thing to do ...

Comment: @trojanfoe: Rob Mayoff suggests [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827319/forcing-an-object-to-deallocate-under-arc) that `autorelease` is useful for ensuring the immediate `dealloc` of `UIView`s - I thought that this might apply to my situation, but it seems to have had no effect. I'll leave it in until I know it's useless though.

Comment: You are right about `willMoveToParentViewController` and it seems counter-intuitive to me as well.  I like the idea suggested by @danypata of setting `child=nil` before calling the notification, however I still feel the real solution lies in coding around the "relying on the child being dealloced" requirement in the observer.  Why not set a flag in the child saying "I am dead" if it's non-`nil`.

Comment: @MikePollard: it's a bit difficult to concisely explain why I'm relying on the dealloc. Suffice it to say that it's not something I can easily change, hence why I'm looking to solve it this way.

Comment: @trojanfoe: setting `child = nil` had no effect, and I wouldn't expect it to, since it already goes out of scope before the notification is fired?

Comment: Ok, I'm out, good luck.

Comment: Sure that makes sense.  How about the idea of not testing for `dealloced` but rather than the child is detached from its parent, either using a private flag or testing its hierarchy?

Comment: @MikePollard: thanks for the advice anyway, I agree this isn't the best way to go, but I have to work with what I've got...

Comment: @trojanfoe: I guess that's what I'll have to do... thank you for your advice ;-)

Comment: No probs. I guess we can take a clue from `_afterCACommitHandler` in your stack. CA presumably being CoreAnimation. Even though your code is finished with the ViewController and it's View the system probably needs to reference them it until it has finished all the rendering that results from your code...

Comment: You forgot a call to `didMoveToParentViewController:` after `removeFromParentViewController`. Also, what happens if you send the notification in the next runloop iteration? Put the line of code sending the notification inside a method, then call that method using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with the delay set to `0.0f`.

Comment: @datwelk. Actually, my code is correct AFAIK (it's just the usage of `willMove` and `didMove` is massively unintuitive: see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13) for clarification, as well as the conversation above between @trojanfoe and I).

Comment: @datwelk: I do, however, like your suggestion for delaying the notification - how about posting it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the notification in the next runloop iteration:

```
- (void)removeChildWithIndex:(NSUInteger)Index 
{
    ChildViewController *child = [_children objectAtIndex:Index];

    //Remove the child from the VC hierarchy
    [child willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [child.view removeFromSuperview];
    [child removeFromParentViewController];
    [child didMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    //Remove the child from array
    [_children removeObjectAtIndex:Index];

    //Post a notification for anyone who might care
    [self performSelector:@selector(_postRemoveChildNotification) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
}

- (void)_postRemoveChildNotification 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RemovedChildNotification object:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is the `autoreleasepool` whcih

> Autorelease pool blocks provide a mechanism whereby you can relinquish
>   ownership of an object, but avoid the possibility of it being
>   deallocated immediately

So basically the `autoreleasepool` will help you removing the ownership of the objects inside the autorelease block but will guarantee that they are not release immediately.

So what you have to do is remove the `autoreleasepool` block and let your code as is and at the bottom of your code you can also make the child nil `child = nil` this will also help your class that receive the notification.

Also don't write code that will base on the fact that some objects will be deallocated when your code is executed. The SO can't guarantee that one object will be deallocated immediately after a method is called. This is just a bad practice, if you can you should rethink your implementation.

Comment: The `autoreleasepool` is there because [a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827319/forcing-an-object-to-deallocate-under-arc) led me to believe that it was needed. Either way, `child` goes out of scope before the notification is fired.

Comment: -1 because removing `autorelease` and setting `child` to `nil` does not change anything.

Comment: Ok, so if an answer dosen't solve your problem you down vote it ? In my opinion, if an answer is completely wrong you down vote it, but in this case, your problem can be in another place. Anyway you should post the code  where you are handling the notification, the code where you are adding the view controller and the autorelease pool should be removed.

Comment: Yes, if an answer is incorrect I will downvote it - nothing personal, it's just the best way to help future users. Also, I won't remove `autoreleasepool` yet - it's just your word against @robmayoff that I don't need it. I won't be posting the code which responds to the notification as it's irrelevant here - it's not easy to change the reliance on the `dealloc` and I'd rather just have an answer to the question that I asked :)

Comment: Regarding the `autoreleasepool` states clearly in the apple docs that it should be use when you are creating lots of temporary objects (not your case here), and prevents the objects to be deallocated immediately and you want exact the opposite thing.

Comment: What's your opinion of Rob Mayoff's answer in the question I linked to above?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `autorelease` does nothing here: Using `CFGetRetainCount` indicates that the retain count of `child` changes from 1 to 3 when I call `removeFromSuperview`. This suggests to me that one explanation for the behaviour I'm seeing is that there may be a temporary object created in reponse to `removeFromSuperView`, which retains an autorelease reference to `child` and is therefore only released when the RunLoop next processes its autorelease pool.

Comment: If this is the case then, as per [Rob Mayoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827319/forcing-an-object-to-deallocate-under-arc), creating an inner autorelease pool might cause `child` to be released earlier.

Comment: I based my answer on the apple docs regarding the autreleasepool (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html). Also when you call the `removeFromSuperView` your view controller is not autoreleased, there are a strong references to it one from your children array and one from your view controllers child array (don't  know if the are the same) so `removeFormSuperview` is not the problem here since there is a strong reference after calling the method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30268/discussion-between-danypata-and-sjwarner)